# I got something wrong with my C++ code about the function "Assert"

Tags: c++

I was copying the code from the textbook, but things went wrong with this

```
void moveToPos(int pos) {       
    assert((pos>=0) && (pos <= cnt), "Position out of range");
    curr = head;
    for (int i = 0; i< pos; i++)
        curr = curr->next;
}
```

The compiler says

```
 [Error] there are no arguments to 'Assert' that depend on a template parameter,
         so a declaration of 'Assert' must be available [-fpermissive].
```

I couldn't figure that out. Please help me.

Thank you guys.
This is my first time to ask a question on StackOverflow. Please forgive me for not knowing how to format.
Here are the codes that may be related to this problem.

```
#ifndef LLIST_H
#define LLIST_H
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "List.h"

    void moveToPos (int pos){
        Assert ((pos>=0)&&(pos<=cnt),"Position out of range");
        curr= head;
        for(int i=0;i<pos;i++){
            curr=curr->next;
        }
    }
    const E& getValue() const{
        Assert ((curr->next !=NULL),"No value");
        return curr->next->element;
    }
```

Comment: This codes are related to the data structure, link list.

Comment: The code snippet does not compile, as it is a snippet and incomplete.  I was unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: C++ is case sensitive. Your title and the text of your question talk about `Assert` but your code uses `assert`. There is no `Assert` in the C++ standard library. Whatever is going on depends on details that you haven't shown, specifically, what `#include` directives come before this code.

Comment: Please, provide [mcve]

Comment: And, please, don't edit the question by dumping all of your code into it. Take some time to trim down the code so that you have the smallest piece of code you can come up with that shows the problem when it's compiled.

Comment: The error message is related to "Assert" with a capital A, are you certain this is the place the error points to ? Anyway, have you included the `<cassert>` header ? Also, `assert()` only takes 1 argument, not 2.

Comment: Textbooks tend to omit required headers in the code examples for simplicity. If you check out https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert you will find that you need to include cassert.

Comment: Where did you find out about the function `Assert()`? Can you  link to its documentation?

Comment: @Reus That only takes **one** parameter and doesn't start with a capital letter. You gave it **two** parameters and started it with a capital `'A'`.

Comment: @Galik  Thank you. But why does the textbook give two parameters to assert?

Comment: @Galik It runs successfully with two parameters.

Comment: I would imagine the book would explain that. It seems to be using a completely different macro/function.

Comment: @Galik It is becoming weird. 'Assert ((pos>=0)&&(pos<=cnt),"Position out of range");'. It worked, with two parameters and the 'A'.

Comment: `C++` is *case sensitive*. `assert()` and `Assert()` are two completely different things. `assert()` takes only one parameter. But `Assert()` is not a standard function/macro. If you want to ask about it, you should link to its documentation.

Comment: @Galik Thank you a lot, man. You helped me a lot. I am just a beginner. Appreciate your patience with me.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The added code, while not quite complete, improves the question.

Comment: Despite my vote to reopen, the code still doesn't show the problem. Someone has, apparently, defined a function named `Assert`, but there is nothing here that indicates where that definition comes from.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you, this is my first time to ask a question on Stack Overflow, I got a lot to learn.

Comment: @PeteBecker  But I know what the problem is, Galik and you have mentioned where the problem is.

Comment: BTW, without additional code I'm guessing, but `(pos>=0)&&(pos<=cnt)` looks wrong - perhaps `pos<cnt` is correct?

Comment: @KenY-N actually, `(pos>=0)&&(pos<=cnt)` is right.

Answer (score 1):

`assert()` takes only one argument: The condition to check. If the check fails, it prints the line number and the condition that was checked.

So, your code should be:

```
assert((pos>=0) && (pos <= cnt));
```

Comment: "_but it still doesn't work_" Doesn't work.. How? It is useless problem description on its own.